# Getting floating point exception: 8

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I have this line in my code (ll is long long int):

```
ll d = (x / ( (y / 1000000) - 1) );
```

which seems to be causing this floating point exception error.
However when I change it to:

```
ll d = (1000000*x)/(y-1000000);
```

the error disappears. Simple algebra will lead you to believe that they both are one and the same thing.

Here is the full code, which is for UVa problem 10660, Grocery Store. https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=643&page=show_problem&problem=2177

```
//Problem Link: https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=643&page=show_problem&problem=2177
//Problem type: Complete Search

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <cmath>
#include <assert.h>
#include <bitset>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iomanip> //cout << setprecision(n) << fixed << num

typedef long long int ll;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //freopen("output.out", "w", stdout);
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int a = 1; a*4 <= 2000; a++) {
        for (int b = a; a+3*b <= 2000; b++) {
            for (int c = b; a+b+2*c <= 2000; c++) {
                ll x = a+b+c;
                ll y = a*b*c;
                if (y <= 1000000) continue;
                //ll d = (x / ( (y / 1000000) - 1) );
                ll d = (1000000*x)/(y-1000000);
                if (d < c || x + d > 2000) continue;
                if ( abs( (x + d) / 100.0 - ( y * d) / 100000000.0) < 1e-8 ) {
                    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << a/100.0 <<  " " << b/100.0 << " " << c/100.0 << " " << d/100.0 << endl;
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << cnt << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I change it to `ll d = (x / ( (y / 1000000.0f) - 1) )` however, then the error disappears, but I get a Wrong Answer, and the number of lines in the output is only 717, whereas it should be 949 (I had to google the answer to figure out this weird issue :/)

Comment: You get SIGFPE because of the integer divide-by-zero.

Comment: I dont think that's possible. "if (y <= 1000000) continue;" y is never equal to 1000000 so there should be no divide-by-zero.

Comment: `(x / ( (y / 1000000) - 1) )` can cause divide-by-zero as long as `y / 1000000 == 1`.

Comment: ... how will y / 1000000 == 1 if y is never 1000000 ?!

Comment: check dasblinkenlight's answer :)

Comment: Yeah, just realised :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no floating-point arithmetic going on here: everything is done in integers (specifically, `long long int`s).

This means that when `y` is between `1000000` and `1999999`, inclusive, the result of the division `y / 1000000` is going to be `1`. Hence, subtracting `1` from it would lead to zero denominator, and a division by zero exception.

Your second expression will produce the same result only when `y` is equal to `1000000`, but the program is going to crash with the same exception.

The trick to solving problems of this kind is keeping numerator and denominator separate, and performing your math entirely in integers, i.e. without floating point numbers. Constructing a simple class for representing rational numbers should help simplifying your code.

Comment: But why am I getting a WA with ll d = (x / ( (y / 1000000.0f) - 1) ); ?

Comment: @SinByCos Because you get into floating point numbers mixed with `long long`s. They have different ranges. `double`s have only 52 bits of precision, but a much higher range, while `long long`s have 63 bits precision, and a narrower range. Mixed math near the border cases produces results that may be grossly off from the target.

Answer (score 0):

The numeric code is a bit flag of exactly what error you hit (8 means division by zero).

These are the other bits:

```
enum {
    XCP_INVALID=0,
    XCP_OVERFLOW,
    XCP_UNDERFLOW,
    XCP_DIV_BY_ZERO,
    XCP_INEXACT,
    XCP_NXCP  
    };
```